# Pagespeed Failed to read cache clean timestamp /var/cache/pagespeed/!clean!time!. Doing an extra cache clean to be safe

Tags: nginx, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

Stumbled upon the following error on nginx pagespeed running a stateless docker container hosted in cloud run. When testing locally i don't get the error after deployment the error is logged after almost every request.

```
2022-05-14 22:05:03.316 EAT2022/05/14 19:05:03 [warn] 14#50: [ngx_pagespeed 1.13.35.2-0] Failed to read cache clean timestamp /var/cache/pagespeed/!clean!time!. Doing an extra cache clean to be safe.
Default
2022-05-14 22:05:22.935 EAT2022/05/14 19:05:22 [warn] 14#50: [ngx_pagespeed 1.13.35.2-0] Failed to read cache clean timestamp /var/cache/pagespeed/!clean!time!. Doing an extra cache clean to be safe.
Default
2022-05-14 22:05:25.775 EAT2022/05/14 19:05:25 [warn] 14#50: [ngx_pagespeed 1.13.35.2-0] Failed to read cache clean timestamp /var/cache/pagespeed/!clean!time!. Doing an extra cache clean to be safe.
Default
2022-05-14 22:05:31.825 EAT2022/05/14 19:05:31 [warn] 14#50: [ngx_pagespeed 1.13.35.2-0] Failed to read cache clean timestamp /var/cache/pagespeed/!clean!time!. Doing an extra cache clean to be safe.
Default
2022-05-14 22:05:32.419 EAT2022/05/14 19:05:32 [warn] 13#52: [ngx_pagespeed 1.13.35.2-0] Failed to read cache clean timestamp /var/cache/pagespeed/!clean!time!. Doing an extra cache clean to be safe.
Default
2022-05-14 22:05:35.767 EAT2022/05/14 19:05:35 [warn] 14#50: [ngx_pagespeed 1.13.35.2-0] Failed to read cache clean timestamp /var/cache/pagespeed/!clean!time!. Doing an extra cache clean to be safe.
Default
2022-05-14 22:05:37.443 EAT2022/05/14 19:05:37 [warn] 14#50: [ngx_pagespeed 1.13.35.2-0] Failed to read cache clean timestamp /var/cache/pagespeed/!clean!time!. Doing an extra cache clean to be safe.
Default
2022-05-14 22:05:43.798 EAT2022/05/14 19:05:43 [warn] 14#50: [ngx_pagespeed 1.13.35.2-0] Failed to read cache clean timestamp /var/cache/pagespeed/!clean!time!. Doing an extra cache clean to be safe.
Default
2022-05-14 22:05:46.655 EAT2022/05/14 19:05:46 [warn] 14#50: [ngx_pagespeed 1.13.35.2-0] Failed to read cache clean timestamp /var/cache/pagespeed/!clean!time!. Doing an extra cache clean to be safe.
Default
2022-05-14 22:05:49.654 EAT2022/05/14 19:05:49 [warn] 14#50: [ngx_pagespeed 1.13.35.2-0] Failed to read cache clean timestamp /var/cache/pagespeed/!clean!time!. Doing an extra cache clean to be safe.
```

As you can see the error is logged after almost every request....everything works but this log is just annoying and means something is not right.

Answer (score 0):

### Whats the issue

The user that run nginx cannot write to these directory.

**Config causing the error.**

```
pagespeed FileCachePath "/var/cache/pagespeed/";
pagespeed CreateSharedMemoryMetadataCache "/var/cache/pagespeed/" 102400;
```

### Solution

- Create Directory `v3`
- Create Directory `shm_metadata_cache`
- Create File `!clean!time!`

```
...

RUN mkdir -p /var/cache/pagespeed/shm_metadata_cache && mkdir -p /var/cache/pagespeed/v3 && touch /var/cache/pagespeed/!clean!time!
...
```

**Give all permission to the Directories and file**

```
...

RUN chmod 777 /var/cache/pagespeed/shm_metadata_cache && chmod 777 /var/cache/pagespeed/v3 && chmod 777 /var/cache/pagespeed/!clean!time!
...
```

See more about the issue here:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-pagespeed-ngx/issues/1516